# Aptana Studio 2.0: How to checkout SVN Project to SFTP remote dir?

Tags: eclipse, svn, aptana, subclipse

If you're familiar with the excellent Aptana Studio IDE, you know it's based on Eclipse. You also know it comes pre-packaged with SFTP capability. I need to work on a remote server, where I have Apache installed; SFTP is ideal for this.

I've installed the Subclipse plugin, and I can access and checkout projects from the Repo. I can create a new project from SVN source, which will download all the source to my chosen workspace or a specified location.

But I can't figure out a way to combine these features! I need to create a Project on a remote server via SFTP but I need to link the source to a repository.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Good question, I have wondered this myself when I dabbled in Aptana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is that you can't.  The SVN libraries cannot manage a working copy that is not on your local disk.  You need to work on your project on local file system.  You can then either use some kind of SFTP synch solution with the remote filesystem, or you can commit your files and use a post-commit hook or some other process to update the files on the Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Add a plugin called esftp , you create your project from a repository and and set the remote server configuration then you can upload files to any server and commit the changes to your svn server

http://sourceforge.net/projects/esftp/

Answer (score 0):

Try out ExpanDrive 3 
http://www.expandrive.com/expandrive

It works, but it is slow. Depends on the internet speed that you have.
For example, you can checkout from the SFTP Networkdrive (Z:)

Answer (score 0):

These descriptions are for AptanaStudio3.

1)If you are using SVN as your project repository , first install subversion plugin and then checkout the project using subversion. You will be able to find the checked out project in SVN Repositories view

2)Right click on checkout out project and select the option 'checkout'. This will ask you for desired workspace location.

3)Go to workspace and right click on your project and select 'Publish' => 'Deployment Settings' and provide your server sftp settings. And select 'Automatically sync your changes with remote site'

And you are done, ready to go whatever changes your are doing in your local workspace is synced with remote.This worked for me.